# Split list based on first character - Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I am new to Python and can't quite figure out a solution to my Problem. I would like to split a list into two lists, based on what the list item starts with. My list looks like this, each line represents an item (yes this is not the correct list notation, but for a better overview i'll leave it like this) :

```
***
**
.param
+foo = bar
+foofoo = barbar
+foofoofoo = barbarbar
.model
+spam = eggs
+spamspam = eggseggs
+spamspamspam = eggseggseggs
```

So I want a list that contains all lines starting with a '+' between .param and .model and another list that contains all lines starting with a '+' after model until the end.

I have looked at enumerate() and split(), but since I have a list and not a string and am not trying to match whole items in the list, I'm not sure how to implement them.
What I have is this:

```
paramList = []
for line in newContent:
    while line.startswith('+'):
        paramList.append(line)
        if line.startswith('.'):
            break
```

This is just my try to create the first list. The Problem is, the code reads the second block of '+'s as well because break just Exits the while Loop, not the for Loop.
I hope you can understand my question and thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: "Doesn't do the job" doesn't help at all. What happens? How do you expect the second block to be read at all? And please don't call a list a dict, that's two different concepts.

Comment: Can you show us an example of the result you need on each list?

Comment: sorry for calling a list a dict, what i am ultimately trying to do is create a dictionary consisting of dict = { 'foo':'bar', 'foofoo':'barbar'} etc. so I guess I just jumped ahead there ;) for now i'm just trying to take one step at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is really a simple task that can be accomplish using list slices and list comprehension:

```
data = ['**','***','.param','+foo = bar','+foofoo = barbar','+foofoofoo = barbarbar',
     '.model','+spam = eggs','+spamspam = eggseggs','+spamspamspam = eggseggseggs']

# First get the interesting positions.
param_tag_pos = data.index('.param')
model_tag_pos = data.index('.model')
# Get all elements between tags.
params =  [param for param in data[param_tag_pos + 1: model_tag_pos] if param.startswith('+')]
models =  [model for model in data[model_tag_pos + 1: -1] if model.startswith('+')]

print(params)
print(models)
```

Output

```
>>> ['+foo = bar', '+foofoo = barbar', '+foofoofoo = barbarbar']
>>> ['+spam = eggs', '+spamspam = eggseggs']
```

**Answer to comment:**

Suppose you have a list containing numbers from 0 up to 5.

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Then using list [slices](http://techearth.net/python/index.php5?title=Python:Basics:Slices) you can select a subset of `l`:

```
another = l[2:5]   # another is [2, 3, 4]
```

That what we are doing here:

```
data[param_tag_pos + 1: model_tag_pos]
```

**And for your last question:** *...how does python know param are the lines in data it should iterate over and what exactly does the first paramin param for paramdo?*

Python doesn't know, You have to tell him.

First `param` is a variable name I'm using here, it cuold be `x`,  `list_items`, whatever you want.

and I will translate the line of code to plain english for you:

```
# Pythonian
params =  [param for param in data[param_tag_pos + 1: model_tag_pos] if param.startswith('+')]

# English
params is a list of "things", for each "thing" we can see in the list `data` 
from position `param_tag_pos + 1` to position `model_tag_pos`, just if that "thing" starts with the character '+'.
```

Comment: yes this is exactly what i was looking for, i knew there was a simple, concise way to do it, i just don't have enough practice yet to see it... 
but again, i am having a hard time wrapping my head around the "important" part in the [] brackets: how does python know `param` are the lines in data it should iterate over and what exactly does the first `param`in `param for param`do?

Comment: @moringana are you sure? ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {}
for line in newContent:
    if line.startswith('.'):
        cur_dict = {}
        data[line[1:]] = cur_dict
    elif line.startswith('+'):
        key, value = line[1:].split(' = ', 1)
        cur_dict[key] = value
```

This creates a dict of dicts:

```
{'model': {'spam': 'eggs',
           'spamspam': 'eggseggs',
           'spamspamspam': 'eggseggseggs'},
 'param': {'foo': 'bar',
           'foofoo': 'barbar',
           'foofoofoo': 'barbarbar'}}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, that is an interesting concept, however not really what i need. ultimately I would like to create a dictionary with the key=value pairs and I can't see that working with your suggestion

Comment: @JonClements - then it should raise a NameError if a '+' line comes before a '.' line.

Comment: @eumiro yeah... not sure it's a significant improvement over `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` - but is a bit more obvious imho

Comment: @eumiro okay so if i understand correctly in the `cur_dict = data.setdefault(line[1:], {})`part you are taking away the dot and adding the word to the cur_dict as key whilst creating an empty dictionary as the value, right? why exactly do you use .setdefault, what is Default about creating the dictionary entry?
then for the `+` lines part you split the line at the equal sign and store the first part without the plus sign as key and the rest as value. how does python know what to store in These variables, like that it will end up with exactly two strings after Splitting?

Comment: i am coming from C and all These methods and what they can do seem a bit wondrous to me... ;)

Comment: @moringana - you ask the right "beginner" questions. I have added a little bit of explicity to my code. "setdefault" is not needed if each ".section" comes exactly once. In ".split(' = ')" I await that there is exactly one ' = ' occurrence. With an extra 1 I split it not more than once. If there is no ' = ', the line will raise an exception. I wrote the minimal answer for you. It may always be improved.

Comment: Thank you very much! i just answered myself my own question about how python knows when to Switch from the model to the param dict, thats why you called it `cur_dict`I suppose ;)

Answer (score 1):

> I am new to Python

Whoops.  Don't bother with my answer then.

> I want a list that contains all lines starting with a '+' between
>   .param and .model and another list that contains all lines starting
>   with a '+' after model until the end.

```
import itertools as it
import pprint

data = [
    '***',
    '**',
    '.param',
    '+foo = bar',
    '+foofoo = barbar',
    '+foofoofoo = barbarbar',
    '.model',
    '+spam = eggs',
    '+spamspam = eggseggs',
    '+spamspamspam = eggseggseggs',
]

results = [
    list(group) for key, group in it.groupby(data, lambda s: s.startswith('+'))
    if key
]


pprint.pprint(results)
print '-' * 20
print results[0]
print '-' * 20
pprint.pprint(results[1])

--output:--
[['+foo = bar', '+foofoo = barbar', '+foofoofoo = barbarbar'],
 ['+spam = eggs', '+spamspam = eggseggs', '+spamspamspam = eggseggseggs']]
--------------------
['+foo = bar', '+foofoo = barbar', '+foofoofoo = barbarbar']
--------------------
['+spam = eggs', '+spamspam = eggseggs', '+spamspamspam = eggseggseggs']
```

This thing here:

```
it.groupby(data, lambda x: x.startswith('+')
```

...tells python to create groups from the strings according to their first character.  If the first character is a '+', then the string gets put into a True group.  If the first character is not a '+', then the string gets put into a False group.  However, there are more than two groups because  consecutive False strings will form a group, and consecutive True strings will form a group.

Based on your data, the first three strings:

```
***
**
.param
```

will create one False group.  Then, the next strings:

```
+foo = bar
+foofoo = barbar
+foofoofoo = barbarbar
```

will create one True group.  Then the next string:

```
'.model'
```

will create another False group. Then the next strings:

```
'+spam = eggs'
'+spamspam = eggseggs'
'+spamspamspam = eggseggseggs'
```

will create another True group.  The result will be something like:

```
{
    False: [strs here],
    True:  [strs here],
    False: [strs here],
    True:  [strs here]
}
```

Then it's just a matter of picking out each True group: `if key`, and then converting the corresponding group to a list: `list(group)`.

**Response to comment:**

> where exactly does python go through data, like how does it know s is
>   the data it's iterating over?

groupby() works like do_stuff() below:

```
def do_stuff(items, func):
    for item in items:
        print func(item)


#Create the arguments for do_stuff():

data = [1, 2, 3]

def my_func(x):
    return  x + 100 

#Call do_stuff() with the proper argument types:

do_stuff(data, my_func) #Just like when calling groupby(), you provide some data 
                        #and a function that you want applied to each item in data

--output:--
101
102
103
```

Which can also be written like this:

```
do_stuff(data, lambda x: x + 100)
```

`lambda` creates an *anonymous* function, which is convenient for simple functions which you don't need to refer to by name.

This *list comprehension*:

```
[ 
    list(group) 
    for key, group in it.groupby(data, lambda s: s.startswith('+')) 
    if key 
]
```

is *equivalent* to this:

```
results = []

for key, group in it.groupby(data, lambda s: s.startswith('+') ):
   if key:
       results.append(list(group))
```

It's clearer to explicitly write a for loop, however list comprehensions execute much faster.  Here is some detail:

```
[ 
    list(group)  #The item you want to be in the results list for the current iteration of the loop here:
    for key, group in it.groupby(data, lambda s: s.startswith('+')) #A for loop
    if key #Only include the item for the current loop iteration in the results list if key is True
]
```

Comment: ok wow, as a newbie to python coming from C I am still discovering all these neat methods and modules that do everything!
could you please explain the line `results = [
    list(group) for key, group in it.groupby(data, lambda s: s.startswith('+'))
    if key
]` in words so i can better understand the "flow" of the language? so `key`is True or False? and where exactly does python go through `data`, like how does it know `s`is the data it's iterating over?

Comment: @moringana, See my response at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my questions, it helps a lot :) shouldn't the Output of `do_stuff` be 101, 102, 103 though?

Comment: @moringana, Yep.  I simplified the function, and I forgot to repost the output.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing things step by step. 
1) Grab every word from the array separately. 
2) Grab the first letter of the word. 
3) Look if that is a '+' or '.'

Example code:

```
import re
class Dark():
    def __init__(self):
        # Array 
        x = ['+Hello', '.World', '+Hobbits', '+Dwarves', '.Orcs']
        xPlus = []
        xDot = []
        # Values
        i = 0
        # Look through every word in the array one by one. 
        while (i != len(x)):
            # Grab every word (s), and convert to string (y).
            s = x[i:i+1]
            y = '\n'.join(s)
            # Print word
            print(y)
            # Grab the first letter.
            letter = y[:1]
            if (letter == '+'):
                xPlus.append(y)
            elif (letter == '.'):
                xDot.append(y)
            else:
                pass
            # Add +1
            i = i + 1
        # Print lists
        print(xPlus)
        print(xDot)

#Run class
Dark()
```

Comment: Doing something like `y = '\n'.join(s)`, is a common gotcha in python.  Strings are also iterable, like lists, except each element is a single char. You almost never want to pass a string to the `join` method, because it will create a list of each character. That's why you had to do this cryptic thing `s = x[i:i+1]` to make it work. That construct uses a slice of a list to return a new list with length 1. i.e. is it going to return the list `['+Hello']` rather than the string `+Hello` . You can avoid that gotcha by just doing `s = x[i]` ,  skip the join and just `print(s)`.

Comment: It's common in Java and languages that don't have functions (only methods) to use a class for something like this, but in Python it's a bit overkill to hijack a class `__init__` method when you can define a function. Another construct that is very C/Java is the while loop, which forces you to count an `i` variable, very easy to forget to increment it. In Python you already know, and are making use of,  the `len(x)` which you can use in a for loop. e,g, `for i in range(len(x))`. You can also skip getting the index and loop directly over the list: `for s in x:` and then s is already each word.